# unity3d5x Error building Player: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a new Unity developer and I tried to create a simple scene in Unity using the tutorial. When I build the project, it is showing the following errors when I press Android build:

[image]

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance ofan     object
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer..ctor ()
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity    /build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
>       UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Comment: Check if you set up package name in Player Settings. File > Build Settings > Player Settings > Bundle Identifier.

Comment: Yes. I set Bundle identifier according in company name and product name.